# JavaScript - Getting return values from functions

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, submit

I want to make submit button enabled only if both functions return true. I can use only JavaScript. Can someone help?

Here's the code:

```
function func(obj) {
       if (obj.value.length > 4) {
           alert("Longer than 4.");
           return false;
       } else if (obj.value.length < 2) {
           alert("Shorter than 2.");
           return false;
       } else {
           return true;
       }
}

function func1(obj){
    if (obj.value == "abc"){
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Isn't abc");
        return false;
    }

}
```

```
<form method="" action="">

    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" onblur="func(this)"><br>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text" onblur="func1(this)"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled>

</form>
```

Comment: just do `if( func( obj ) && func1( obj ) ){ /* Here goes your code if both is true */ }`

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze that's probably better put as an answer than a comment. :)

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze i think it will not work with `obj` you have to replace it by some value.

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridz anyway, i cant get it to work that way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to make some change in your code.

First, you have two input with same id. You need to fix that.
Add a method to the form, and change the name and id of your submit button like so:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text1" onblur="check();"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text2" onblur="check();"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn" disabled>
</form>
```

On onblur event we can add a function that check your condition:

```
function check() {
    var obj1 = document.getElementById('text1');
    var obj2 = document.getElementById('text2');
    if (func(obj1) && func1(obj2)) {
        document.getElementById('submit_btn').disabled = false;    
    } else {
        document.getElementById('submit_btn').disabled = true;    
    }        
}
```

and enable submit.

Answer (score 2):

There's many solutions for your case, I suggest to call `check()` method after execution of the both function and it will check the validity of conditions then disable or active the submit button :

```js
function check()
{
    var input_1 = document.getElementById('text-1').value;
    var input_2 = document.getElementById('text-2').value;
    
    if(input_1.length < 4 && input_1.length > 2 && input_2 == "abc")
        document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute('disabled');
    else
        document.getElementById('submit').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
}

function func(obj)
{
    if (obj.value.length > 4) 
        alert("Longer than 4.");
    else if(obj.value.length < 2)
        alert("Shorter than 2.");
    
    check();
}

function func1(obj)
{
    if (obj.value != "abc")
        alert("Isn't abc");
    
    check();
}
```

```html
<form method="" action="">
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text-1" onblur="func(this)"><br>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text-2" onblur="func1(this)"><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It does help, thanks! Tsung-Ting Kuo's and TGrif's solutions are very good also, had a problem whose answer to choose..

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier, you could give your submit button an id (we'll call it "submitButton").

```
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled>

...

var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitButton");

if(func(obj) && func1(obj)) {         
     submitBtn.disabled = false;
} else {
     submitBtn.disabled = true;
}
```

If you can't give it an id for some reason, you can select all input elements using document.selectElementByTagName and then iterate through them to find the submit button.

Comment: Are you sure ?? no it will not work because i can't see where you declare the `obj`.

Comment: Please add the full answer.

Comment: This is the full answer. The question is asking for a solution that works when func and func1 return true, not for test data that forces them to be true.

Answer (score 1):

One plausible way is to set the attributes of the button instead of returning values.

1. Add two variables and change the two functions.
2. Add / change the id of the inputs.

```js
        var test1 = false;
        var test2 = false;

        function func(obj) {
            if (obj.value.length > 4) {
                test1 = false;
            } else if (obj.value.length < 2) {
                test1 = false;
            } else {
                test1 = true;
            }
            if (test1 && test2) {
                document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
            }
        }

        function func1(obj) {
            if (obj.value == "abc"){
                test2 = true;
            } else {
                test2 = false;
            }
            if (test1 && test2) {
                document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
            }
        }
```

```html
        <form method="" action="">
            <input type="text" name="text" id="text1" onblur="func(this)"><br>
            <input type="text" name="text" id="text2" onblur="func1(this)"><br>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
        </form>
```

This might not be an elegant solution, but I tested it and it works.

Comment: The solution from TGrif is more elegant than mine, but my codes can deal with the situation that "the user has valid inputs first, but changed them to invalid ones afterwards" - in this case the submit button should still be disabled.

Comment: You're absolutly right, thx for the compliment. I'll update my answer for this case.